# Python - Extract Numbers Separated by Hyphen from String

Tags: python, string, expression, extract

I am trying to extract 2 numbers (Depth From and Depth To) separated by hyphen in a dataframe column (name Depth). While the first number is extracted correctly, the second number is not. I have tried many methods.

```
ConvCore = pd.read_csv(r'ConvCore.csv', encoding='cp1252')
ConvCore.columns = ['Depth', 'k', 'phi', 'Well']
ConvCore['DepthFrom'] = ConvCore['Depth'].str.extract('([0-9.]+)')

#ConvCore['DepthTo'] = ConvCore['Depth'].str.extract('-([0-9.]+)')
#for i in ConvCore:
    #ConvCore['DepthTo'] = re.search(r'(\d+)-', ConvCore['Depth'][i-1])
    #ConvCore['DepthFrom'] = ConvCore['Depth'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
    #DepthTo = ConvCore['Depth'].str.extract('(?P<digit1>[0123456789])').astype(float)
    #ConvCore['DepthTo'] = ConvCore['Depth'].str.split("-")
    #ConvCore['DepthFrom'] = re.match(r'(\d+)', ConvCore['Depth']).group()
```

[image]

Comment: While regex could very well work, for your case, it looks like a **str.split("-")** approach should suffice? You can then get your "from" and "to" strings from that result and convert them back to floats

Comment: try, ``ConvCore['Depth'].str.split('-', expand =True)`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
ConvCore['DepthFrom'] = ConvCore['Depth'].str.split("-", expand=True)[0]
ConvCore['DepthTo'] = ConvCore['To'].str.split("-", expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: You could just set ``expand = True`` in the split & get it done in one-liner

Answer (score 0):

You can split the values and then assign the new values to the dataframe. I used a sample dataset to simulate your scenario,

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': ['20-30', '40-60', '80-90', '0-10'],
    ...:
    ...:                    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
    ...:
    ...:                    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
    ...:
    ...:                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

In [5]: ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.num_legs.str.split('-').tolist(), columns = ['x1', 'x2'])

In [6]: df[ ndf.columns ] = ndf.values

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
       num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen  x1  x2
falcon    20-30          2                 10  20  30
dog       40-60          0                  2  40  60
spider    80-90          0                  1  80  90
fish       0-10          0                  8   0  10
```

So in your case, the code should be somthing like,

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(ConvCore.Depth.str.split('-').tolist(), columns = ['DepthFrom', 'DepthTo'])

ConvCore[ ndf.columns ] = ndf.values
```